# New CME Functionality in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1

Tags: cme, 2013-sp1

I was pleasantly surprised by the Start Location context-menu options in SDL Tridion 2013 SP1.

[image: Start Location context menu includes Use Current Location, Reset to Default, and Go to Start Location]

I didn't see it on the [What's New list for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-6FE1B7B8-A6E0-488D-A98B-7C866FA5B0B1). Is there a list of other Content Manager Explorer changes and/or do you know of other updates?

**Update** -- I think these are also related to 2013 SP1:

- Experience Manager seems to have a new `Open in Form View` option.
- Experience Manager Workflow related component links Component Presentations on the site
- Experience Manager Workflow related pages link to webpages

Comment: nice find, i hadn't noticed that either